# self-referencing generic inheritance in c#

Tags: c#, odata

i saw some c# asp.net source code written as below:

```
public class EntityInstanceContext<TEntityType> : EntityInstanceContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EntityInstanceContext{TEntityType}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public EntityInstanceContext()
        : base()
    {
    }
```

can anyone help me to understand why the generic type is subclassing from non-generic one? and what is benifit of designing in that way?

Comment: Were there any type constraints on the generic class?

Comment: Microsoft description is very clear! "An instance of EntityInstanceContext<TEntityType> gets passed to the self link (HasIdLink, HasEditLink, HasReadLink) and navigation link (HasNavigationPropertyLink, HasNavigationPropertiesLink) builders and can be used by the link builders to generate links." where is the problem?

Comment: See also IEnnumerable and IEnnumerable<T>...

Answer (score 3):

The .NET TypeSystem is a very powerful one.
Imagine the following scenario. I'm writing a class called `MyTuple` which is a poorly coded clone of the BCL `Tuple` class:

```
public class MyTuple<T1, T2> {
    public T1 Item1 { get; private set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; private set; }

    public MyTuple(T1 item1, T2 item2) {
        this.Item1 = item1;
        this.Item2 = item2;
    }
}
```

And then I realize I want to make a **factory kind of method** for that type
so that I can successfully hook into the type inference system and not specify `T1` and `T2` when I don't have to like so:

```
new MyTuple<int, string>(123, "test"); // which is also a bit redundant
```

So I'm writing the method I was talking about in a class, let's call the class `Factory`:

```
public class Factory {

    public static MyTuple<T1, T2> Create<T1, T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2) {
        return new MyTuple<T1, T2>(item1, item2);
    }

}
```

That way, I'm happier when writing:

```
var tuple = Factory.Create(123, "test"); // and tuple is inferred to be of <int, string>
```

Now what would happen if I renamed `Factory` to `MyTuple`:

```
public class MyTuple {

    public static MyTuple<T1, T2> Create<T1, T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2) {
        return new MyTuple<T1, T2>(item1, item2);
    }

}
```

In short: **nothing bad**

It is simply the case that I now have 2 completely distinct types:

- MyTuple (nongeneric)
- MyTuple < T1, T2 >

They have nothing in common, they are different types.

And am I allowed to say that `MyTuple<T1, T2>` just happens to extend `MyTuple` ?
Well, as long as `MyTuple` is neither `static` nor `sealed`, **yeah, sure** !

```
public class MyTuple { ... }
public class MyTuple<T1, T2> : MyTuple { ... }
```

So in your case it's nothing more that `Mammal` extending `Animal` or ... `Tiger` extending `Mammal`.
It's not like `Mammal of a weirder sort` extending `Mammal of a good ol' classical sort`.

Comment: correcting obvious mistake, that if this was helpful should be upvoted. BTW: how I get here, searching for self-referencing odata entities ?